# Flutter TextForm field padding on validation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a TextFormField issue is when its showing validate error its adding some padding on bottom or spacing don't know

My code

```
                          Container(
                            height: Height * 0.08,
                            width: Width * 0.9,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: userNumber,
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter a valid email';
                                }
                                return null;
                              },
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular'),
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                errorStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                                ),
                                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), width: 1),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), width: 1),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                filled: true,
                                hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xffbdbdbd),
                                    fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular'),
                                hintText: "Email",
                                labelStyle: new TextStyle(
                                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                                    fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular'),
                                labelText: 'Email',
                                fillColor: Colors.white70,
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: kPrimaryColor, width: 1),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Issue :

[image]

[image]

Its fine if not validation error but when validation error comes its height reduce or something happen

Answer (score 0):

Use `contentPadding`:

```
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Enter Something',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  ),
)
```